# Redis keys alternative

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, redis, node-redis

I have a Redis server with 2 keys. I'm trying to fetch both the keys and combine them into 1 response. I'm using node-redis.

```
var response = {};
RedisClient.keys('*', function (err, keys) { // gets all keys
  async.each( // asynchronously maps over them and parses the values
    keys,
    function (err, key) {
      RedisClient.get(key, function (err, value) {
        if (err) throw err;
        responsekey] = JSON.parse(value);
      });
    },
    function () {
      res.send(response); // finally sends response object
    }
  );
});
```

This gets all keys, maps over them asynchronously, and finally parses the values and sends them. The problem is that the redis docs and every resource I've read has said not to use keys. Is there another way to do this in node using SCAN?

Comment: does node client support `mget`, if so use that one?

Comment: Yes it does. However when I try to parse the result I get: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 233872`. I don't get this error if I just include one key.

Comment: using mget you will get list of values you need to parse each of them and merge them.